# Web api routing use only RoutePrefix

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have default routing in my webapi which looks like

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                "Web API Data type action",
                "api/v{Version}/{siteId}/{controller}"
                );
```

Now i want to add routing to my controller which will be different something like

```
api/v{Version}/{controller}
```

So what i did i added

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v{Version}/{controller}")]
```

It works, but i can access my controller also by default routing. IS this any way to to limit routing if controller has routeprefix then use only this one. I also have idea to devide my controller to 2 namespaces and then i can limit in routing by namespace

Comment: Have you tried using Areas?

Comment: Yes areas could be an option.

Comment: But its not any MVC, its webapi and generally for my understanding its a bit different its like frontend and backend. In my case its same api, but I am going to have 2 different level of routing